# Single or multiple lock objects

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

I've been researching nested and multiple locks, but I haven't found where this specific scenario has been addressed.

```
class x
{
Method1()
    {
    Lock (object)
        {
        Method2();
        }
    }


Method2()
    {
    Lock (object)
        {
        //do stuff
        }
    }

}//close class x
```

Can the lock objects be the same or do they have to be different?

Is there an advantage of one approach over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be the same, since `lock` (Monitor) is [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) in .NET.

This is mentioned in the documentation for [Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx):

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

Since the same thread can enter the lock using the same object more than once, the above code will work fine sharing the same synchronization object.